# DNS NS Record in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I just bought a Virtual Private Server and I want to configure my website and the `DNS Server` on the same server and of course IP.

I created a `DNS Zone` "domain.com", after I finished, a `SOA` record and NS record was added by default. Then I created the A record that points to the server `IP 204.93.156.XXX`.

The `NS` record added by default has as FQDN the server name and its IP address

**Question**

I have read that I should have two NS records with the format

```
ns1.domain.com -> IP 
ns2.domain.com -> IP
```

But in my case the first one is `FQDN -> IP`
what should be the second on `ns2.domain.com -> IP`

If I do this it gives me an error:

```
"IP for this server cannot be found"
```

I'm new to the configuration of `DNS`.

Answer (score 1):

ns2.domain.com would be for a second DNS server.  If you only have one DNS server, then you will only have one NS record.  Redundant NS servers are recommended, but if your website is small, you can probably get away with one.

Answer (score 0):

The second NS is mandatory, if you want to host DNS official zones (for most TLDs). For example `.de` hosting nameservers must be at least two machines, connected to (at least) two international backbones, located in two [different class B networks](https://www.denic.de/service/nameservice/).

If you want to host your own private zone (foo.local), you can do whatever you want. If you want to host zones like a 'official' ISP, you need at least two different servers on two backbones. Other TLDs may have different requirements to do that.

No restrictions apply for internal nameservers; I have a lot of customers with an internal DNS that has a copy of the companys official zone, too. This allows mutliple [Split-Brain (or Split-Horizon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) scenarios. Some of the just use one machine, some use multiple.

If you want to host a official zone, just ask your ISP or some DNS-Providers you trust, if they can supply the secondary. In most cases (at least in my experiance), ISPs are happy to help, if you ask the right people. Usually they have bigger DNS deployments where one zone more or less doesn't count.